# linux : A simple Linux Script is showing some comamnds on to the screen

Tags: java, linux

When i ran a script to execute a java Application to showed up this screen

**sh Joii.sh**

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available

    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -age
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathna
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, se
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
```

This is my script

```
echo "Start time: " `date`


export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin

LIB_DIR=/home/rvarre/NewPdpapiToplist1/lib

export CLASSPATH=.:$LIB_DIR/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:$LIB_DIR/log4j-1.2.8.jar:$LIB_DIR/mail.jar:$LIB_DIR/marketdata-b1.1.jar:$LIB_DIR/middleware.jar:$LIB_DIR/pdpapi-all.jar

echo $CLASSPATH

#Debugging Classpath

#JVM Parameters

java -classpath=$CLASSPATH com.tata.topListQuoteSamples.TOPLISTSample
echo "End time: " `date`
```

Comment: You invoked your java in a bad way. Try do do it manually first.

Comment: There should be no equals operator on your classpath.  `java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.tata.topListQuoteSamples.TOPLISTSample`

Answer (score 1):

You have an equal sign in the `-classpath` parameter, but it expects space.

Try

```
java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.tata.topListQuoteSamples.TOPLISTSample
```

BTW, when you are supplying the CLASSPATH, you do not need to export it, and when it is exported you do not need to supply it. So in you case this should also work

```
    java com.tata.topListQuoteSamples.TOPLISTSample
```

And as commentators have said, you problem is in the way you invoke the `java` command, the shell script is OK. So try in manually first.